# How to find some words contain in string?

Tags: php

I wish to do this in PHP find `some words` contain in a string

```
  if (strpos($str,array("select","update","insert into","delete") !== False){
    echo "string contain SQL statements";
  }
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: modify your question please... which is `word` and which is `string`???

Comment: The code you posted will already find those words in a string?

Comment: not really ,some case found ,and some case no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to detect if any of the word is contained in the string, you can do:

```
$sql_words = array(...);

if(count(array_intersect(explode(' ', strtolower($str)), $sql_words)) > 0) {

}
```

Although if a string contains `select`, it does not mean that it is a SQL query. But I guess that depends on the context.

Depending on the string you might also want to use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function as follows:

```
$string_to_be_searched_in = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
$sqlWords = array("insert", "update", "delete" ...);

foreach($sqlWords as $word) {
    if(strstr($string_to_be_searched_in, $word) != FALSE) {
        echo "The given string is an SQL statement";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $string = "i m where ?";
 $searchfor = array("select","from","where","and","and",update,"set","insert","into","value");

foreach($searchfor as $v) {
  if(false !== strpos($string, $v) ) {
    //Found a word
    echo 'Found '.$v;
    break;
  }
}
```

Reference:

*[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)*

also study

case sensitive *[strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)* and
case insensitive : *[stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)*

Comment: What about if the string contains a word like `somewhere`?

Comment: And your `if` statement is actually incorrect. It should be: `if(strpos($string, $v) > -1)`.

Comment: i have checked...this was working fine for me. although it fails on somewhere

Comment: Sorry, my comment is not correct (to much JavaScript). It should be `if(strpos($string, $v) !== false)`. From the documentation: *This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.*

Answer (score 0):

The function you want to use is [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). It uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match patterns to a string, and returns the number of times the pattern matched - if you pass through an array as a parameter, you can also use it to extract information form the string (in your example, you could pull what the query was).

You should read [these pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) on using regular expressions with PHP, and [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) will allow you to test regular expressions.